# Why does a tbf remain grouped after filling NAs with na.locf?

Tags: r, random

```r
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df_a <- iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(mean_petal_length = mean(Petal.Length))
sample_n(df_a, 2)
```

This returns 2 random rows of summarized `iris` as expected, though there is only one row per group, `Species`.

However, the other example below seems to behave differently.

```r
df_b <- iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    mutate(Petal.Length = na.locf(Petal.Length))
# Now df_b is the same with iris in terms of data contents
# since there's no missing vales in Petal.Length
sample_n(df_b, 60)
```

I expected to get 60 random rows of `df_b`, but this gives me an error message: *`size` must be less or equal than 50 (size of data), set `replace` = TRUE to use sampling with replacement*.

I can see it's because there are only 50 rows per group `Species`, and I have to `ungroup` after `mutate` in this case to get my expected output. Still I don't get the reasons why there is such difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `na.locf` and it has got to do with how `summarise` and `mutate` behave with `group_by`. Let me try to explain you using the same example.

After `summarise` the grouping is lost. Check

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(mean_petal_length = mean(Petal.Length)) %>%
  mutate(n = n())

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Species    mean_petal_length     n
#  <fct>                  <dbl> <int>
#1 setosa                  1.46     3
#2 versicolor              4.26     3
#3 virginica               5.55     3
```

You would expect `n` to be 1 if it is grouped by `Species` but it shows as 3 indicating that there is no grouping.

Hence, when you do `sample_n` after summarise it samples from the total dataframe which has 3 rows and select 2 random rows.

However, with `mutate` the case is different.

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(Petal.Length = mean(Petal.Length)) %>%
  mutate(n = n())

# A tibble: 150 x 6
# Groups:   Species [3]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species     n
#          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <int>
# 1          5.1         3.5         1.46         0.2 setosa     50
# 2          4.9         3           1.46         0.2 setosa     50
# 3          4.7         3.2         1.46         0.2 setosa     50
# 4          4.6         3.1         1.46         0.2 setosa     50
# 5          5           3.6         1.46         0.2 setosa     50
# 6          5.4         3.9         1.46         0.4 setosa     50
# 7          4.6         3.4         1.46         0.3 setosa     50
# 8          5           3.4         1.46         0.2 setosa     50
# 9          4.4         2.9         1.46         0.2 setosa     50
#10          4.9         3.1         1.46         0.1 setosa     50
# … with 140 more rows
```

The grouping is still present and it tries to select 60 rows from each group whereas in reality it has only 50 rows, hence, the error.

`?summarise` mentions

> Value - An object of the same class as .data. One grouping level will be dropped.

whereas `?mutate` mentions

> Value - An object of the same class as .data

So with `summarise` only one level of grouping is dropped. Take an example with `mtcars`

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, am) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(mpg))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl    am  mean
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4     0  22.9
#2     4     1  28.1
#3     6     0  19.1
#4     6     1  20.6
#5     8     0  15.0
#6     8     1  15.4
```

It is still grouped by `cyl` and grouping by `am` is lost.

Answer (score 1):

from the group_by documentation it says :

> Most data operations are done on groups defined by variables. group_by() takes an existing tbl and converts it into a grouped tbl where operations are performed "by group". ungroup() removes grouping.

So even if it looks like the same tibble you have to think of it as `split(iris, iris$Species)` in `base`.

```r
library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df_b <- iris %>%
        group_by(Species)
attributes(df_b)
#> $names
#> [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
#> [5] "Species"     
#> 
#> $class
#> [1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
#> 
#> $row.names
#>   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
#>  [18]  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34
#>  [35]  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51
#>  [52]  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68
#>  [69]  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85
#>  [86]  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102
#> [103] 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119
#> [120] 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136
#> [137] 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
#> 
#> $groups
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Species    .rows     
#>   <fct>      <list>    
#> 1 setosa     <int [50]>
#> 2 versicolor <int [50]>
#> 3 virginica  <int [50]>

# equivalent in base R to:
str( split(iris, iris$Species) )
#> List of 3
#>  $ setosa    :'data.frame':  50 obs. of  5 variables:
#>   ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:50] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#>   ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:50] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#>   ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:50] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#>   ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:50] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#>   ..$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ versicolor:'data.frame':  50 obs. of  5 variables:
#>   ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:50] 7 6.4 6.9 5.5 6.5 5.7 6.3 4.9 6.6 5.2 ...
#>   ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:50] 3.2 3.2 3.1 2.3 2.8 2.8 3.3 2.4 2.9 2.7 ...
#>   ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:50] 4.7 4.5 4.9 4 4.6 4.5 4.7 3.3 4.6 3.9 ...
#>   ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:50] 1.4 1.5 1.5 1.3 1.5 1.3 1.6 1 1.3 1.4 ...
#>   ..$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
#>  $ virginica :'data.frame':  50 obs. of  5 variables:
#>   ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:50] 6.3 5.8 7.1 6.3 6.5 7.6 4.9 7.3 6.7 7.2 ...
#>   ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:50] 3.3 2.7 3 2.9 3 3 2.5 2.9 2.5 3.6 ...
#>   ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:50] 6 5.1 5.9 5.6 5.8 6.6 4.5 6.3 5.8 6.1 ...
#>   ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:50] 2.5 1.9 2.1 1.8 2.2 2.1 1.7 1.8 1.8 2.5 ...
#>   ..$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...

# if you want to use a function not applied by group
sample_n(df_b %>% ungroup() , 10)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
#>  1          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica 
#>  2          6.1         2.9          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#>  3          5           3            1.6         0.2 setosa    
#>  4          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5 virginica 
#>  5          6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 versicolor
#>  6          5.8         2.7          4.1         1   versicolor
#>  7          6.6         3            4.4         1.4 versicolor
#>  8          7.7         2.8          6.7         2   virginica 
#>  9          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#> 10          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa
```